# Multiple developers keeping CouchDB in sync with eachother

Tags: couchdb

I'm considering using CouchDB for an upcoming web development project.

**What is the best way to keep the CouchDB document repo in sync between various developers who are all running the application locally?**

An Example: Suppose Developer A creates a new view or design document in Couch or just simply adds a field to an existing view.  They also check in some client-side code that expects that field to be on the CouchDB view.  Developer B comes in and updates to the latest source code, pulling down Developer A's client-side changes.  How does Developer B get the Couch changes that accompany the client-side code?

In a typical RDBMS, this would be accomplished by checking a set of SQL files or database migrations into the SCM system.  After Developer B updates his code he would run the new SQL or migration scripts to upgrade his database schema.

Perhaps in Couch there is a way to export/import design docs and view definitions and check those into an SCM system?  Perhaps I just need my RDBMS background brainwashing to be deprogrammed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've typically kept .js files of my views' map and reduce functions, and stored those in my code repository.  A common pattern is to have a folder for each view, and a separate .js file for each view function (map/reduce).  An example:

```
views/
    tags/
        map.js
        reduce.js
    users/
        map.js
        reduce.js
```

The content of `views/tags/map.js` is simply the JavaScript map function, for example:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.tags && doc.tags.length) {
        for(var index in doc.tags) {
            emit(doc.tags[index], null);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then manage your views any way you choose, possibly using [CouchApp](http://github.com/jchris/couchapp) or something like it to sync everything to a CouchDB instance.  Of course, I don't know what the "best practice" is, but this is what I've done and it works well with my team.

Answer (score 1):

Low-tech solution:

- Export to file with [couchdb-dump](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/)
- Import from this file with [couchdb-load](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/)

The export-import file format seems to be kind of JSON, making it not unlike moving SQL files around.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's suggestions above is a good one. [DB::CouchDB::Schema](http://github.com/zaphar/db-couchdb-schema) is a perl library that has a script bundled that can export and import your design documents. It might help automate the job for you.